# html ul li slidebar and click to dynamic change selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Continue the question which I ask some days ago, I already achieve my target.

And another question is: if I want to set the `<ul> <li>` with a slidebar,

and hide some `<ul> <li>` object (because it have so many `<ul> <li>`, too much may make the website look complicated)

so if I have 6 `<ul> <li>` object, and I want to show only 3 `<ul> <li>` on the website,

other 3 `<ul> <li>` will hide and if I click `<` or `>`, it will dynamically to change the `<ul> <li>`

make an easy example:

[image]

I want to have a `slidebar` in the `<ul> <li>` bottom, so that I can click the slidebar to left or to right to click what I want.

```js
const links = $(".SwitchURL-small-link")
const modulo = links.length
let selectedIndex = links.index(".action")

$("#smallTitle button").on("click", function() {
  const inc = this.id === "next" ? 1 : -1
  selectedIndex = (((selectedIndex + inc) % modulo) + modulo) % modulo

  links.each((index, link) => {
    link.classList.toggle("action", index === selectedIndex)
  })
})
```

```css
.SwitchURL-small-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.SwitchURL-small-link.action {
  border-bottom: 2px solid#AE96DA;
  color: #AE96DA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="SwitchURL-small-list" id="smallTitle">
  <li class="SwitchURL-smaill-item"> <button id="prev" type="button"> &lt; </button></li>
  <li class="SwitchURL-small-item"> <a href="AA" class="SwitchURL-small-link action" id="SwitchURL0">AA</a></li>
  <li class="SwitchURL-small-item"> <a href="BB" class="SwitchURL-small-link" id="SwitchURL1">BB</a></li>
  <li class="SwitchURL-small-item"> <a href="CC" class="SwitchURL-small-link" id="SwitchURL2">CC</a></li>
  <li class="SwitchURL-small-item"> <a href="DD" class="SwitchURL-small-link" id="SwitchURL3">DD</a></li>
  <li class="SwitchURL-small-item"> <a href="EE" class="SwitchURL-small-link" id="SwitchURL4">EE</a></li>
  <li class="SwitchURL-small-item"> <a href="FF" class="SwitchURL-small-link" id="SwitchURL5">FF</a></li>
  <li class="SwitchURL-smaill-item"> <button id="next" type="button"> &gt; </button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+scroll+horizontal+UL+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungjan thank you, I'm learning how to use stack overflow well.